# How to dynamically change a dependency?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, koin

I have an interface named `CrmRepository` from which I implemented two classes `SuiteCrmRepository` and `OneCrmRepository` which are data sources for my application.

I want to swap the dependency (data source) dynamically whenever the user login with a different account.

I used Koin to inject the repositories into the view model in constructor:

```
class ModuleViewModel(private var crmRepo: CrmRepository) :ViewModel() {}
```

and declare the module in koin like this:

```
fun provideCrmRepository(
): CrmRepository {
    return if (crmType == CrmType.SUITE) {
        SuiteCrmRepository()
    } else if (crmType == CrmType.ONE){
        OneCrmRepository()
    }
}

single {
    provideCrmRepository()
}
```

The problem is once the `ModuleViewModel` is created, a single instance of `CrmRepository` is created too, which can't be changed or created again when a new `ModuleViewModel` is created but after i changed the `crmType` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **[factory](https://start.insert-koin.io/#/quickstart/android)** keyword instead of **single**.

> we declare our MySimplePresenter class as factory to have a create a new instance each time our Activity will need one.

By using single keyword, Koin providing same instance of object.

Change the lines to;

```
factory {
   provideCrmRepository()
}
```

Another solution might be unload and load modules whenever ***crmType*** changed.

Comment: thanks, and how does Koin knows when the Activity will need one ?
does that means it won't be single instance ?

Comment: I am not sure about it. You can check the documents about core concept, modules, scopes and injecting paramaters.
https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/modules